# How to do a one-time operation under abstract class

Tags: java, abstract-class

I am developing a webApplication based on Java EE.

I have an abstract class, in which I need to have a one-time operation (a database call).

So below in the sample code, I pasted it inside its constructor, but don't know why the constructor is not getting invoked.

Please tell me how to solve this.

```
public abstract class Preethi {

 Preethi()
 {
    System.out.println("hirerew");
 }

 public static void main(String args[])
 {
    int a  = 12;

    if(a==0)
        System.out.println("a");

    if (a==12)
        System.out.println("12");
 }

}
```

Comment: you dont create any instance of this class (Know it is abstract but still sth can inherit from it). Then call super to invoke the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You never create an instance of abstract class Preethi. Why do you expect the constructor to get called? Make a non-abstract subclass and create an instance of it and then the constructor will be called. main is static, it can be called without Preethi being realized.

```
public class X extends Preethi
{ /* Your implementation here */}
```

Then in main:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
  Preethi preethi = new X(); // This will call the constructor of Preethi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is not being invoked because `main()` method is called without instantiating a main class.

To invoke it - you need to create an object of `Preethi` explicitly.

UPD. as anio suggests - you need to subclass `Preethi` and instantiate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating object of `Preethi`. In order to make call to constructor, You have to  remove abstract keyword from class and create it's object

Or create anonymous inner class and it's object as :

```
new Preethi() {
   // abstract method impl
};
```

Or create sub class of Preethi, and create object of it.

FYI: You can create object references of any abstract class or interfaces. You can not create object of them.

And I think making main class abstract really does not make any sense. Atlease to me.(Tell me if I am wrong)

Answer (score 0):

See the code below:

```
public abstract class Preethi {

    // constructor:
    Preethi() {
        System.out.println("hirerew");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // call the constructor:
        new Preethi() {};  // "{}" needed because our class is abstract.
    }

}
```

The point here is that you don't always have to create a new class, but can define a 'one-time' class next to the constructor. For example:

```
public abstract class A {
    public abstract void foo();
    public A() { foo(); }
}
```

You could do the following:

```
A a = new A() { 
    public void foo() { 
        System.out.println("hello"); 
    } 
};
```

The output would simply be "hello". A similar method could also be utilized for interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Although abstract classes cannot be used to instantiate objects, they can be used to create object references, because Java's approach to run-time polymorphism is implemented through the use of superclass references. Thus, it must be possible to create a reference to an abstract class so that it can be used to POINT TO A SUBCLASS object.

You can make it not abstract, or create a subclass that invokes super() on your abstract class.